# how could I pass swift custom component's properties from js world

Tags: ios, react-native

I have custom component written by swift and I want to pass some custom properties from js world,

but I really don't know how to do it, provide some main code below.

---

**Demo-Bridging-Header.h**

```
#import "RCTBridgeModule.h"
#import "RCTViewManager.h"
```

**CollectionViewManagerBridge.m**

```
#import "RCTView.h"
#import "RCTViewManager.h"


@interface RCT_EXTERN_MODULE(CollectionViewManagerSwift, RCTViewManager)

@end
```

**CollectionViewManagerSwift.swift**

```
@objc(CollectionViewManagerSwift)

class CollectionViewManagerSwift : RCTViewManager, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {
  
  let contentCellIdentifier = "CellIdentifier"
  var collectionView: UICollectionView
  
  override init() {
    let layout = CustomCollectionViewLayout()
    let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: CGRectZero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    
    collectionView.registerClass(CustomCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: contentCellIdentifier)
    collectionView.directionalLockEnabled = false
    collectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    
    self.collectionView = collectionView
  }
  
  override func view() -> UICollectionView! {
    self.collectionView.delegate = self
    self.collectionView.dataSource = self
    
    return self.collectionView;
  }

  // ... some other code

}
```

In addition, I also have **CustomCell.swift** and **CustomCollectionViewLayout.swift** which be used above,

these code work fine when I call `<CollectionViewManagerSwift />` in `render()` method from js world,

but how could I pass properties from js world like `<CollectionViewManagerSwift customProperty={customProperties} />`, and how could I define `customProperty` in my swift code?

maybe I don't express clearly, thanks for your time.

---

#### follow-up

I try to add `customProperty` in **CollectionViewManagerBridge.m**

```
#import "RCTView.h"
#import "RCTViewManager.h"


@interface RCT_EXTERN_MODULE(CollectionViewManagerSwift, RCTViewManager)

RCT_CUSTOM_VIEW_PROPERTY(customProperty, NSArray, CollectionViewManagerSwift)
{
  NSLog(@"%@ -- %@", json[0], json[1]);
}

@end
```

then I call it from js world

```
<CollectionViewManagerSwift customProperty={['foo', 'bar']} />
```

I get the value in Xcode output

```
2016-02-27 17:58:07.167 Demo[49690:12639774] foo -- bar
```

but how could I get the `customProperty` in **CollectionViewManagerSwift.swift**?

thanks again.

regards

Comment: I could not figure this one out, So I had to mix the code to get mine working. I found this in the react-native site.

export properties with `RCT_CUSTOM_VIEW_PROPERTY` macro in your custom native component, then just use them in React Native as if the component was an ordinary React Native component.

And remember cross-language properties don't support `callbacks`

Comment: @AKADER please see my follow up content, I try your words but I have no idea to get the property in my swift source :(

Comment: @E_Jovi Very curious to know if you ever got this working. We're running into the same issues. Do have a link to a repo with a working example.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if there is another way (a better one) to achieve it.

Anyway, I have a UI library written in **swift** and, I wanted to create a  module (node + pod) for the RN so that I can use it in other RN projects.

```swift
@objc(SampleSwiftViewManager)
public class SampleSwiftViewManager:RCTViewManager {
    
    @objc(setSrc:)// --> this is important
    public func setSrc(obj:Dictionary<String, Any>) {
        guard let currentView = obj["view"] as? SampleSwiftView,
              let src = obj["json"] as? String else {
            return
        }
        
        currentView.setSrc(src: src)
    }
    
    
    public override func view() -> UIView! {
        return SampleSwiftView()
    }
}

class SampleSwiftView: UIView {
    
    // custom view implementation ....
    
    // example prop method
    func setSrc(src:String) {
        // ....
    }
}
```

And in Objective-C

```objectivec
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <React/RCTViewManager.h>
#import <React/RCTUIManager.h>

@interface RCT_EXTERN_MODULE(SampleSwiftViewManager, RCTViewManager)

RCT_CUSTOM_VIEW_PROPERTY(src, NSString, NSObject) {
    [self performSelector:@selector(setSrc:) withObject:@{@"view":view, @"json":json}];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to: "Implement the -(UIView *)view method" as is mentioned in this document: http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-components-ios.html#content

That is where you would be able to initialize your CollectionView.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, I already call `view` method in my code above from `CollectionViewManagerSwift.swift`, but I don't know how to define property that be passed from js world in swift code :(

Answer (score 0):

To add more details in answer of @Suryavel.

if you want to pass multiple params, you can do like below also

```objectivec
// .m
RCT_CUSTOM_VIEW_PROPERTY(padding, NSDictionary, NSObject) {
    [self performSelector:@selector(setPadding:withObj:) withObject:view withObject:json];
}
```

```swift
// .swift
@objc(setPadding:withObj:)
func setPadding(view: MyView, obj: Dictionary<String, Int>) {
        print(view)
        print(obj)
}
```